# Random Number Generator Not Working - discord.py 3.x.x

Tags: python, discord.py

I'm trying to make a bot that, when asked to gamble, will pick a random number for the bot and yourself. My current code is this:

```
if message.content == ('-gamble'):
     embed=discord.Embed(title="Challenge", description="To find a village, you must gamble with the 
     bot himself. Rolling the dice...", color=0xff0000)
     await message.channel.send(embed=embed)
     await asyncio.sleep(2)
     choice = random.randrange(0,1)
if choice == 0:
     embed=discord.Embed(title="Your Losing Gamble", description="You lose!\n\nThe bot 
     rolled 13 and you rolled 7.", color=0xff0000)
     await message.channel.send(embed=embed)
if choice == 1:
     embed=discord.Embed(title="Your Winning Gamble", description="You win!\n\nThe bot 
     rolled 4 and you rolled 15.", color=0xff0000)
     await message.channel.send(embed=embed)
```

There's no error code. It just **always** lands on a losing gamble. I've tried spamming it, but it'll just always land on a loss. I've got no idea what's going on, any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Thank you both so much! This worked.

Answer (score 2):

You are asking to chosse between "0" and "0", as the second number is excluded.

Try

```py
choice = random.randrange(0,2)
```

See Randrange documentation  : https://docs.python.org/3/library/random.html

Answer (score 1):

`randrange(0, 1)` is returns always 0.

If you want to choose 0 or 1, you can use `randrange(0, 2)` or `randint(0, 1)`